# aws ec2 instance volumes, does this charge even if the ec2 instance in shut down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I have two ec2 instances running in aws which are currently stopped (I am using the free tier just to experiment with Azure).  I noticed that even though the instances are in the stopped state I seem to be incurring a charge for (this is all I have)

S3 - Puts (This contained the sample applications which I uploaded to test)
EBS - Volumes

Is this the case? or am I missing something here.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/, ebs volumes could be costing u money. Check if you are still under https://aws.amazon.com/free/. You should also check your billing page on aws console to get a idea on why are u incurring charged. https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home

Comment: I am using the EC2 instances to test Docker and I noticed that as part of creating the EC2 instance its creating EBS volumes, could this be incurring the charge?

Plus I noticed that S3 Puts is incurring a charge, what is S3 put used for.  When I navigated to the bucket I noticed that there were a number of applications under the S3 bucket which I used to test deployments, I assume this is what is incurring the cost?

Comment: Your S3 storage is incurring charge, also do you have any unused Elastic IP that is also charged.

Comment: The EBS volumes will have the files for the host os and the docker images. So the EBS volume could endup incurring cost if you go beyond the free tier. Dont you see the details on the billing page?

Comment: Actually this is all the information I see

S3 - Puts - 40.50 already  forecast 156%
EBS Volumes - 30.56 already forecast 118%

This gives rise to another question, can I try ECS without EBS volumes?

Comment: You can use instance store volumes.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: Also try coreos, if amazon linux is forcing u a ebs volume. I like coreos to run my containers.

Comment: The standard ECS-ready Amazon Linux instances have 2 EBS devices, one for root and one for docker data. It's not trivial to change that.

Comment: Why does it need an EBS volume?  Cant they store the images on the host os itself?

Comment: They could, but if the instance would restart for whatever reason, you'd lose all your data. Most AWS instances are moving to EBS storage for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big the EC2 instances and their storage are.

Stopped instances themselves don't cost any further money, but EBS storage, S3 and other moving parts like ELB's will still cause charges.

You get 30GB of EBS storage free per month in the free tier, so if the total of the EBS in use is more than that, you pay.

https://aws.amazon.com/free/ nicely describes the limits of the free tier.

For further cost calculations, check out https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: thanks for this, so if I'm using ECS then where does the s3 put come in?

Comment: ECS itself doesn't normally use S3, so, not sure what you mean. If your test setup is using S3 for something, then that causes cost.
S3 put means the action of uploading something to S3.